# Onmouseover hover effect in SVG when hosted on Sharepoint

Tags: svg, hover, onmouseover, onmouseout

Could You help me that:
I have svg file:
[FILE_SVG](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz0pGbURRJQpM04zZ29kckttckU/view?usp=sharing)
 exported from Illustrator. Designated target for me is to add "hover" effect to it (it could be Zomm effect or color changing), but at the end file will be uploaded into company's intranet site which is running on Sharepoint. I've made it with CSS but internal template is cutting whole css part/code.

As i know it's possible to be done with Javascript...
Cany You help Me with that or provide an extewrnal link to start with (for amateurs ofc).
Thanks for any help...

Comment: I'm not a SharePoint user, so I don't know what you mean by the CSS being "cut".  Where was the CSS?  In an external file? Inside the SVG?  How are you embedding the SVG in your page.  All of this is important information in order to help you.

Comment: Our company sherepoint back-end user interface allow Us to embedd some code thru " View/Edit source code (HTML)" button. of course source code has impact only on certain frame. We can't overwrite base elements like top menu, side bar etc. So when i'm editing code and emedding svg into it - sharepoint cuts CSS with an information: "Specific HTML code was ignored and wasn't saved". Probably whole site template has own css and this is why "other" css is being cut out.

Answer (score 0):

If your internal template is cutting your custom CSS, then it's likely going to cut your custom JavaScript as well. To my knowledge, you cannot embed hover effects into an SVG. But if you have access to the HTML and CSS or JavaScript then start with the following and experiment.

So you need to have three files.

1. Your SVG
2. Your HTML
3. Your CSS

in your SVG, it's going to have some weird code like:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="30" height="30" stroke="black" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>
</svg>
```

copy that into your HTML, and add an id to the svg:

```
<div class="svg-wrapper">
    <svg id="mySVG" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <rect x="10" y="10" width="30" height="30" stroke="black" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

and something like this in your CSS:

```
#mySVG {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}
#mySVG:hover {
    width: 250px;
    height: 375px;
    fill: blue;
}
```

if you do decide to do JavaScript instead of CSS, it will look something like:

```
document.getElementById("mySVG").addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
    event.target.style.fill="blue";
});
```

Try this tutorial for using SVG: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Try this tutorial for JavaScript hover events: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve hover effects using SVG's built in SMIL animation feature.  Sharepoint presumably won't strip that.

```html
<svg>
  <circle cx="150" cy="75" r="50" fill="red">
    <set attributeName="fill" to="green" begin="mouseover" end="mouseout"/>
  </circle>
</svg>
```

Note that this won't work in IE though. Which might be a problem if you are a big MS workplace :)

Comment: Thx Paul. It;s nice and easy to achive but You're right... 80% of Users are working on IE... ;-((